# Regex Group Capturing Generation

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the string '924527-28-17-EU' and I also have the string '92XXXX-XX-XX-XX', where the second string is the format for the first. Assume the X-groups will always be separated.

My ultimate goal is to get ['4527', '28', '17', 'EU']. How can I do this?

One thing I was thinking about was somehow getting '92(....)-(..)-(..)-(..)' or something in order to nicely capture those, but I don't really know how to get there.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit: I'm writing in Python.

**Edit: More specifically, I want to get to something like this:

```
    re.search('92(....)\-(..)\-(..)\-(..)', '924527-28-17-EU').groups()
```

Comment: What language/environment are you writing in?

Comment: I'm writing in Python.

Comment: So please tag the question with that, and show us the code you've tried, along with an explanation of what failed.

Comment: My problem is that I literally do not know where to start. I realized I had a problem when replacing 'X' with '.' wouldn't give me specific capturing groups. I don't know how to surround the '....' things with parentheses to get them into groups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear from your question if you are only interested in finding strings which start with 92, or if you are just trying to show that as an example.

If you want are just wanting to trim the first 2 characters off any string and then split you could use:

```
a = '924527-28-17-EU'
b = a[2:].split("-")
# print b returns ['4527', '28', '17', 'EU']
```

Alternatively if you are trying to find strings which specifically start with 92 you could try:

```
if a[:2] == "92":
    c = a[2:].split("-")
#c now returns ['4527', '28', '17', 'EU']
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was unclear about this... it should work regardless of whether there are hyphens or not. This was just an example.

I mean, theoretically, I could replace the X's with '.' and then go through it character-by-character and then add parens to the beginning and ends of '.+' substrings... but I feel like there is a better way.